# iAd Ads shows in landscape mode for portrait only application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have integrated iAd into my iPad application. My application is supported only in portrait orientation. When a user clicks on iAd, the ad opens in the same mode as the iPad. This is a problem, as I only want them in portrait mode (like my app). How do I restrict the ads to portrait mode?